# An item in my array and a string have the same value, but why == evaluate to false?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm working on this code, which will tell if a product is shipped from the US.

```
{% assign USVendors = "
customcat,
gearment,
" %}

{% assign USVendorArray = USVendors | split: "," %}
{% assign ProductVendor = product.vendor | downcase | strip %}
{% assign USShipped = false %}

{% for item in USVendorArray %}
    {% if item == ProductVendor %}
        {% assign USShipped = true %}
        {% break %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ USShipped }}
```

In one product in which `Product.type = "CustomCat"`, `USVendorArray[0]` and `ProductVedndor` both equal `customcat`. And therefore, `USShipped` should be `true`, but it isn't.

I see the problem is in the `if` line, because when I change `==` to `contain`, it just works.

Can you please explain what is wrong with my code?

Comment: My guess would be that `USVendors` has some whitespace before or after the separators, so some of the strings in `USVendorArray` end up with leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: Firstly the `==` boolean should be reserved for numeric values only and not strings. This boolean checks if the chars are a 100% match (in some languages it checks if a class matches another class), which does include formatting options, like Capitial Letter, Spaces etc. The `contain` function checks if the a string has the same characters as another string. I.e., a string, `x = bus` is compared to another string, `y = bus stop` --> `y.contain(x)` will return `true` because `bus stop` contains `bus`. However, `y == x` will return `false` because `bus` is **not directly** equal to `bus stop`

Comment: Thank you @StephenC, I tried ```{% assign USVendors = "customcat,gearment,melaninfulcc" %}``` and it works now. Maybe the line break when assigning values in the initial code causes this problem.

Comment: Thank you @SnipingPoodle for your helpful comment, I edited and figured out how the code was wrong.